# Can't install Composer on Mac (Yosemite)

Tags: php, macos, composer-php

```
localhost:1nbox myusername$ sudo curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | phpmamp
#!/usr/bin/env php
All settings correct for using Composer
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to write bundled cacert.pem to: /Users/myusername/.composer/cacert.pem' in -:403
Stack trace:
#0 -(112): installComposer(false, false, 'composer.phar', false, false, false)
#1 -(14): process(Array)
#2 {main}
  thrown in - on line 403
localhost:1nbox myusername$
```

My `.bash_profile` has:

```
alias phpmamp='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/bin/php'
```

Comment: Try curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo phpmamp

Comment: @TotalWipeOut `sudo: phpmamp: command not found`

Comment: you will have to call php directly i think then `curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/bin/php`

Comment: @TotalWipeOut That returns: `Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to write bundled cacert.pem to: /Users/myusername/.composer/cacert.pem' in -:403`

Comment: sorry i made a typo :/ - have edited my comment. try it again

Comment: Ah man, that worked! I spent like an hour on this problem. Thanks heaps! :)

Comment: Next time you should get [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) then do `brew install composer`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @TotalWipeOut posted above, this command works:

```
curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/bin/php
```

I was able to successfully install composer with MAMP PHP.